# Java Code putting values in hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

A hashmap stores data.

```
 private final Map<VideoObj,Record> _data = new HashMap<VideoObj,Record>();
```

What is the difference between

```
 Record rIn= new Record(video, numOwned+change, numOut, numRentals);
_data.put(video, rIn);
```

And

```
Record r= _data.get(video);
r.numOwned+=change;
```

In which cases can this create problems with the values.

Comment: The first code sample is adding a key/value to the hashmap. The second example is retrieving a key/value and then updating a property. They should be equivalent as far as the value of numOwned for record, assuming the second parameter in the Record constructor populates numOwned.

Answer (score 1):

Video should override equals and hashcode methods and preferably Video class should be made final.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather take the second approach with null check thrown in. And logging.

In that way, program clearly (and concisely) conveys the invariant.

The code is also hinting the value, the Record is a mutable class. So again first doesntt hold any advantage, why spend on memory then.

Lastly remember hashmap is no thread-safe. In this regard though also both are equally unsafe the way they are so far.

Answer (score 0):

The first creates a new `Record` instance and puts it in the map for the key `video`, which would replace the previous value that was stored for that key in the map.

The second changes the current `Record` value stored in the map for the key `video`. However, it doesn't verify that the map actually contains that key, so you might get a NullPointerException.